# react-admin documentation for the update and updateMany previousData parameter

Tags: react-admin

I am implementing a `DataProvider` for `react-admin` and the `update`, `delete` methods have a `previousData` parameter for the update. The parameter doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, and I can't for the life of me think what they could be used for, given you have to provide `id(s)`. What could this possibly be for? Is there genuinely no documentation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `previousData` is usually not used in the dataProvider itself. react-admin uses it for the undoable feature but it may have other use cases like implementing in the dataProvider an audit log with a diff of the records.

Also, note that this `previousData` parameter is only required for the `update` and `delete` but not for `updateMany` nor `deleteMany`